# Css : scrolling horizontal under other element

Tags: css, vuejs2, gantt-chart

I created a Gantt chart and I want that when I scroll horizontally on the days of the month, the cells of the hidden days (from 01 to 04 here) appear (so it would hide the last 4 days on the right).

I've been racking my brain for hours and I can't seem to solve this problem :(

```
.gantt-chart-wrapper {
    height: 581px;
}

.gantt-chart-table {
    border-radius: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gantt-chart-table thead, .gantt-chart-table tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yz3vd7wf/

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, I post a fiddle, not a link to another site :/

Comment: Is your fiddle on another site and this is a link to it? Yes it is.

Comment: No. I have create this fiddle myself. It's not on another site.

Answer (score -1):

To do overflow, you can use CSS **overflow-x:** or **overflow-y:** on the container you want to scroll.

Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: Hi, I know overflow, but when I use overflow, it's my entire table that scrolls, and not my rows under my tasks bloc.